# Fragment inside activity not working

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-fragments

I am creating a simple running app which tracks uses run path.

I am working on the first activity which will display:

- a Google map
- a start button
- a stop button
- and some lables

which will display time distance/timer covered by the user when start button is pressed and user start running.

First I created a default google map activity. I have kept the default code unchanged for now.  This is below:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity{//FragmentActivity
private GoogleMap mMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
if (mMap == null) {
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment)    getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
    }


private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0,   0)).title("Marker"));
}
}
```

The map layout file lookes like this

Note : I have not changes anything in these 2 files and they were auto genrated

Next I created a blank activity with linier layout to add the fragment created above with two button and necessary labels.

```
public class Framwithmap extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_framwithmap);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_framwithmap, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Note: above file was also generated by default

Layout for home screen is below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MyActivity" >

<TextView
    android:text="Activity Title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    android:text="START" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center"
    android:text="RESET" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But all this does not work.

My questions:

1. Is this the correct way to add google map fragment to an activity?
2. How will be the androidmanifest file? Should I add bout activities there or just home activity?
3. The error I get is

> Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main
>   Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface. Any thoughts

Comment: <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

Comment: Have you read through the [**official docs**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)